# Looping a set number of times in C# List

Tags: c#

I am trying to loop only 3 times through a C# List.This is my code so far.

```
IEnumerable<Artist> threeoldest = Artists.Where(Artist=> Artist.Hometown == "Atlanta").OrderByDescending(Artist=>Artist.Age);
```

I only want to get the first 3 rows, since the list is already in descending order.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{                 
    System.Console.WriteLine(threeoldest[i].RealName);                 
    System.Console.WriteLine(threeoldest[i].Age);        
}
```

Comment: Use `Take` after `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: where exactly is your problem? your code looks fine. What is the difference between the actual and the expected result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50523655/34092 may be worth a read.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Take` to truncate the elements from the IEnumerable:

```
Artists.Where(Artist=> Artist.Hometown == "Atlanta")
       .OrderByDescending(Artist => Artist.Age)
       .Take(3);
```

Comment: You should order first and then take.

Comment: In the case you want the first 3 items? you don't want to only sort 3 items you accidently get by the Select but you want to sort all items and than take the first 3

Comment: @Aomine No we are not. OrderBy is lazy, just like most other LINQ methods. It is implementation detail of course, but if the sorting algorithm can determine the top 3 elements it can stop right there without having to sort the remaining ones.
But either way, the OP wanted to take the first 3 artists by age descending from Atlanta, and that's how you do it

Comment: @PéterCsajtai got it now, my bad. thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/20f56c2654ea24dad54c18f3683a8772ff734772/MoreLinq/Extensions.g.cs#L3657 might be an approach to consider if you want to avoid holding the entire sorted list in memory @MarcellTóth.